# Не передается input данные в django form

Tags: python, html, django, form, get

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'orders_home' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Поиск" id="filter" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="button-addon2">Искать</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

строка браузера:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=e1IM8G4z6lPBDguHhhsqDRSj4OSUNBfhL7anQNViAm4Yhl3hxNSv2SlsvtjACyZA`

почему передается только `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, но переменная `filter` не передается?

Comment: а как вы их передаете ?

Comment: я так понимаю, то что внутри form передается? то есть надо получить параметр get  в view, а <input id="filter"> не передается

Comment: Куда вы их передаете? Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: если я их передаю методом get, они должны быть в строке барузера. там их нет. принимаю я их  по средством request

Answer (score 1):

решение в `input` надо не `id` указывать, а `name`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Поиск" name="filter" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
```

*facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте вот так:

```
request.GET.get('filter')
```

Comment: уточняющим вопросам не место в ответе.